# Log systemd service stderr to different file using rsyslog

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, syslog

I have the following config in a systemd service:

```
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=udocit
```

And this rsyslog conf file:

```
if $programname == 'udocit' and $syslogseverity > 5 then {
  action(
    type="omfile"
    FileCreateMode="0640"
    File="/var/log/udocit.log"
  )
& stop
}

if $programname == 'udocit' and $syslogseverity <= 5 then {
  action(
    type="omfile"
    FileCreateMode="0640"
    File="/var/log/udocit.err"
  )
& stop
}
```

The service starts a nodejs app.

I would expect that messages which come from the `console.error()` function, which outputs to stderr, would go to the udocit.err file with this config, but all messages are instead written to the udocit.log file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note, you don't need the `&` before `stop`, as that is used to match a legacy-style filter. In Rainerscript, you are inside a `then` clause, so it is clear what is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `console.error()` might do, but systemd will make all messages written to stdout or stderr generate a syslog entry with a default level of `info` (`SyslogLevel=info`).

To get a different level the lines printed must begin with a string such as `<3>` which is level `error`. Systemd, by default, removes such a prefix and converts the syslog entry severity to it.  See `man systemd.exec` for option `SyslogLevelPrefix` and `man sd-daemon`.

Comment: Is there a similar prefix I can use with journald?
I am trying to do this from a podman container logging to journald.
Then in rsyslog I catch the container logs and log them to a file, but I get the <3> outputted and log severity is INFO

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about journald, and nothing about podman. You should probably post a new question.